# Given $h \in k[x]$, $F(T) \in k[x][T]$ a multiple of $T$, can we find $g \in k[x]$ not a multiple of $h$, such that $F(g)$ is a multiple of $h$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, for example $k=\mathbb{C}$.

Let $F(T) \in k[x][T]$ a multiple ot $T$, namely,
$F(T)=f_nT^n+f_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+f_2T^{2}+f_1T$,
where $f_n,\ldots,f_1 \in k[x]$.

Let $h(x) \in k[x]-k$.

> **Question 1:** Is it possible to find $g(x) \in k[x]$,
> not a multiple of $h(x)$, such that
> $F(g(x))$ is a multiple of $h(x)$?

**Remarks:**

**(i)** Of course, if $g=hr$, for some $r \in k[x]$, then
$F(g)=F(hr)=f_n(hr)^n+f_{n-1}(hr)^{n-1}+\cdots+f_2(hr)^{2}+f_1(hr)$
is a multiple of $h$.

**(ii)** It would be interesting to solve the special case $h=x$, though I am interested in a general $h$.

---

If question 1 has a positive answer, is it possible to generalize to the following situation:

Let $E(T),F(T) \in k[x][T]$, $h(x) \in k[x]-k$.

> **Question 2:** Is it possible to find $g(x) \in k[x]$,
> not a multiple of $h(x)$, such that each of
> $E(g(x)), F(g(x))$ is a multiple of $h(x)$?

My guess is that question 1 has a positive answer, while question 2 not.

---

**Edit:** After receiving helpful comments, I suggest to first concentrate of the special case $F=f_2T^2+f_1T$, $f_2,f_1 \in k[x]$, $h=x$.

Also, I have now noticed that if $h$ divides each of $f_n,\ldots,f_1$,
then $F(T)$ is already a multiple of $h$, so every $g \in k[x]$ is a 'solution' (= $F(g)$ is a multiple of $h$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: For your special case, doesn't $g(x)=x-1$, $F(T)=T^2+T$,  i.e. $F(x-1)=(x-1)^2+(x-1)=x^2-x=x(x-1)$ furnish an example?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I see I misread the question and the question is for fixed h and F, can one always find such a g. Disregard the previous comment.

Comment: @SeanClark, thank you for both comments! Yes, I meant what you mention it your second comment. Anyway, it is nice to have a simple example.

Comment: I guess the answer is sometimes yes and sometimes no, depending on $h$ and $F$. What sort of answer are you hoping to get?

Comment: @Servaes, thank you for your comment. Interesting. Could you elaborate, namely, is it possible to characterize all pairs $F,h$ for which there exists such a $g$? I thought/hoped it was always possible to find such a $g$.

Comment: A simple example for which it is not possible is $F=T$ with any $h$. Or $F=T^k$ with $h$ having no repeated factors.

Comment: @Servaes, very nice.

Comment: I can think of plenty of examples going both ways, which has me leaning towards closing this question as ' too broad', or 'missing context or details' as I think you can come up with plenty of examples yourself. Going through some examples, perhaps you will be able to conjecture some characterization. Or perhaps you will conclude that this is too broad a question, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: To @Servaes point, I think the best one can do here is describe how to take a particular h and F, do some modular arithmetic, and get a (probably nonlinear) system of equations that may or may not be solvable.

Comment: @Servaes, please allow me a few days to think about special cases and edit my question.

Comment: @SeanClark, this is exactly what I meant when I added the linear algebra tag.

Comment: Also, I'm curious what the source of this problem is. It's rather particular; why should $F$ be a multiple of $T$? Is there some other problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Perhaps if we have 'enough' coefficients in F, it is possible to find appropriate $g$.

Comment: @Servaes, I thought it would be easier to concentrate on such $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recasting the first question in terms of modular arithmetic, the question is equivalently whether there is a residue $g(x)$ modulo $h(x)$ such that the residue of $F(g(x))$ is zero. Let $\bar{\cdot}$ denote taking residues mod $h$; we want to know when we can find a $g$ such that $\overline{F(g(x))}=0$.

For the special case $h(x)=x$, all residues are simply elements of $k$, i.e. $\bar g(x)=g(0)$, so $\overline{F(T)}=\sum f_i(0)(T(0))^i$. Thus $\overline{F(g(x))}=0$ if and only if $g(0)$ is a root of the polynomial $\sum f_i(0)t^i$. Note that since $g$ cannot be a multiple of $h$, we also have a constraint that $g(0)\neq 0$.

Thus we see that for our special case, it is highly dependent not only on $F$ but also on the base field $k$. For $k=\mathbb C$, since the field is algebraically closed, the necessary and sufficient condition is that two of the coefficient polynomials in $F(T)$ have non-zero constant terms (edit: or they are all multiples of $x$, of course). For non-algebraically closed $k$,  one needs $\bar F(T)$ to have a nonzero root; otherwise e.g. for $k=\mathbb R$ and $F(T)=T^3+T$, if $F(g(x))$ is divisible by $x$ but $g$ is not, then $g(0)^2=-1$ which is impossible.

---

**EDIT:** Actually the generalization of this case to $h(x)=x^n$ admits a not horrible sufficient condition for there being a solution but does further illustrate the exploding complexities of the naive approach to this problem (not that I have a better idea for an approach, but I've never been much of an algebraic geometer).

Let me introduce the notation that for $f=\sum a_i x^i$, $[f]_i=a_i$. In this case, $\overline{f_i}=\sum_{j\leq n} [f_i]_{j} x^j$ and $\overline{g}=\sum_{j\leq n} [g]_j x^j$. It is not hard to show that for m>1, $$[\overline{g(x)}^k]_m=k[g]_0^{k-1}[g]_m+(\text{expression in }[g]_j,j< m)$$
for any $m$ by the usual binomial counting argument (the degree $m$ term of the product is the sum of all possible products of $k$ monomials, one from each of the $k$ factors, whose total degree is $m$, and if one of the monomials is itself degree $m$, all of the other terms must be degree $0$, and there are precisely $k$ ways to make such a product). In other words, we are seeing a kind of filtration on the coefficients being determined by lower-degree coefficients. In particular, we get the analogous statement $$[\overline{F(g(x))}]_m=\sum_k k[f_k]_0[g]_0^{k-1}[g]_m+(\text{expression in }[g]_j,j< m)$$
(essentially because any terms involving higher order coefficients of the $f$'s involve lower order coefficients from $g$, which as noted have this filtered property).

This is important because we can now make the following observations:

1. $\overline{F(g(x))}=0$ if and only if $[\overline{F(g(x))}]_m=0$ for $0\leq m<n$;
2. $[\overline{F(g(x))}]_0=0$ if and only if $\sum [f_k]_0 [g]_0^k=0$, which is to say that the constant term of $g$ is a root of the polynomial obtained by replacing evaluating $F(T)$ at $x=0$;
3. If $\overline{F(g(x))}=0$ and $g(0)$ is not a root of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xF(T))|_{x=0}$, then $[g]_k$ is determined by $[g]_j$ for $j<m$.

In other words, it is sufficient for $F(T)|_{x=0}$ to have a nonzero, non-repeated root. If the roots are repeated, then something more complex happens whose pattern doesn't jump out at me.

Let's look at two small examples; to improve readability, let me once more change notation by setting $a=[g]_0,b=[g]_1,c=[g]_2,\ldots$ and $A_i=[f_i]_0, \ldots$. Then for $n=2$, we have $\overline{f_i}=A_i+B_ix$ and $\overline{g}=a+bx$, and the equations we get from $\overline{F(g(x))}=0$ are

$$\sum_k A_k a^k=0$$
$$\sum_k (kA_ka^{k-1}b+B_ka^k)=0$$

so if $\sum_k kA_ka^{k-1}$ is not zero, then $b=\dfrac{\sum_k B_ka^k}{\sum_k kA_ka^{k-1}}$. If $\sum_k kA_ka^{k-1}=0$, then we additionally require  $\sum_k B_ka^{k}=0$.

For $n=3$, we get the additional constraint
$$\sum_k (kA_ka^{k-1}c+\binom{k}{2}A_k a^{k-2}b^2+kB_ka^{k-1}b+C_ka^k)=0$$
so once again if $\sum kA_ka^{k-1}\neq 0$, then we can solve for $b$ and $c$; otherwise, we must have $\sum_k B_ka^{k}=0$ and  $\sum_k (\binom{k}{2}A_k a^{k-2}b^2+kB_ka^{k-1}b+C_ka^k)=0$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much.

Comment: Your answer shows how to find $g$ in your first special case $F=T^2+T$. The roots of $t^2+t$ are $0,-1$, excluding $g(0)=0$, yielding infinitely many $g$'s, for example: $g=x-1$, $g=x^2-1$, $x^3-1$, $x^5+x^4-1$, etc.

Comment: Your answer is a good first step for the general case. Thanks again.

Comment: Please, do you have a misprint? It should be $\overline{F(T)}=\sum f_i(0)(g(0))^i$, if I am not wrong.

Comment: I am playing fast and loose with notation there, but T is intended to still be indeterminate so it's not really a typo.  If you like, you can read it as $\overline{F(g(x)}=\sum f_i(0)(g(0))^i$ without losing anything important.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about notation.

Comment: Assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$, $h=x\tilde{h}$, for arbitrary $\tilde{h} \in k[x]$, and at least two of $f_n,\ldots, f_1$ are not multiples of $h$. We wish to find $g \in k[x]-k$, $\deg(g) < \deg(h)$, such that given our $f_j=q_jh+r_j$, $1 \leq j  \leq n$, $\deg(r_j)<\deg(h)$, $g$ satisfies: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i g^i$ is a multiple of $h$. Therefore, in particular, we obtain a necessary but not sufficient condition $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(0) g(0)^i$, so again $g(0)$ is a root of the polynomial $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i(0) t^i$ , but this time this condition is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: So this shows that in question 2 in order to obtain such a $g$, it is necessary that $\sum e_i(0)t^i$ and $\sum f_i(0)t^i$ have a (nonzero? it could be zero, so $g$ and $h$ would have a common factor $x$, But one has to be careful) common root, which would then serve as $g(0)$.

Comment: So this shows that in question 2 in order to obtain such a $g$, it is necessary that $\sum e_i(0)t^i$ and $\sum f_i(0)t^i$ have a (nonzero*) common root, which would then serve as $g(0)$. *nonzero: it could be zero, so $g$ and $h$ would have a common factor $x$. But one has to be careful).

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit! (I have noticed it just now).